# Fastest way to find lines of a file based on column from another larger file in awk

Tags: awk

I have input file (1.csv), has about 0.5M lines and multiple files of CLEANUP_BC_[1-10].csv has about 10 millions. 1.csv has a single field f1 per line while CLEANUP_BC_[1-10].csv  has 2 fields, f1 through f2, delimited by ,.

I want to find all lines from 1.csv where f1 of 1.scv matches f1 of CLEANUP_BC_[1-10].csv, if its matches write a output based on CLEANUP_BC_[1-10].csv file F2 column last digit.

cat 1.csv

```
15192151898
11000000012
11000000019
11000000077
12042050006
12042050053
12042050158
12042050161
12042050178
12042050198
```

CLEANUP_BC_1.csv

```
 15192151898, 732539481
 16133029583, 707751921
 16133636489, 540841871
 16476205207, 770565711
 16132823434, 459659751
 12363335422, 889809091
 14372484755, 739320471
 12368188419, 732539481
 12042050161, 770565711
 17807200578, 744517871
```

CLEANUP_BC_2.csv

```
 12042050198, 592494702
 16134492706, 739754232
 12363321831, 747588192
 19053343880, 432742682
 12262185649, 779803212
 16047157202, 888743762
 19054607842, 789457272
 12505168454, 138011622
 14372156219, 781262852
 12042050158, 765193222
```

Script:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
 hash[$1]; next
 }
 {
    for (i in hash) if (match($0,i)) {print; break}
 }' 1.csv FS=',' CLEANUP_BC_*
```

Expected Output:

cat 1.csv

```
 15192151898, 732539481
 12042050161, 770565711
```

cat 2.csv

```
 12042050198, 592494702
 12042050158, 765193222
```

Comment: `1.csv` is an input file **AND** an output file?

Comment: Do the files contain leading spaces? If not, please remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical awk multiple files processing problem.

The command: (I think the code explains itself)

```
awk -F',' ' fname != FILENAME{fname=FILENAME;idx++}
    idx == 1 {a[$1]}
    idx>1 && $1 in a{print > (fname".out")} ' 1.csv C_*.csv
```

### Note:

- I tested it with gawk
- I simplified your filename a bit. `C_*.csv` you can replace it with the real pattern
- Your `CLEAN_*.csv` files have leading spaces on each line. I've removed them. If your input data really contain those spaces, we need to handle it. It's pretty easy, but I guess the spaces come from your copy&paste.
- After you run the command, you will get 10 (*if there are 10 `CLEANUP_..csv` files, as you said*) `CLEANUP_....csv.out` files, which contain the matched lines
- If you have a lot of input files, you may want to call `close(fname".out")` before switching to a new input file. Or you may get something like "too many opened files" err-msg.

If I run it with your shortened examples, I got:

```
kent$  head *.out
==> C_1.csv.out <==
15192151898, 732539481
12042050161, 770565711

==> c_2.csv.out <==
12042050198, 592494702
12042050158, 765193222
```

Comment: Perfectly works as there is no leading and trailing space in the input records. Thanks a lot help!.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you. you are right! I'll change the `>` in answer. and add the close() statement in case there are many input files.